# Python StatsModels Patsy Work-Around, Predicting With Out of Model Parameters

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, predict, patsy

I am running regressions on data panels of mortgages broken down by year.  All of the variables are categorical, dummy variables.  In some years, there may be certain characteristics or features of mortgages that are not present in other years, so I get a Patsy Error like below:

```
 PatsyError: Error converting data to categorical: observation with value 'Null/Invalid' does not match any of the expected levels (expected: ['Conventional', 'FHA', 'Other Non-Government Loan', 'VA'])
net_gnma_rate ~ C(origination_month) + C(Mortgage_FICO_Bins, Treatment("(720, 900]")) * C(Mortgage_LTV_Bins, Treatment("(0, 80]")) + C(alt_loantype, Treatment("Conventional")) + C(conforming_mtge, Treatment("conforming")) + C(alt_lien, Treatment("1st Lien")) + C(doctype, Treatment("Full Documentation")) + C(alt_occ, Treatment("Owner Occupied")) + C(altpmi3, Treatment("No PMI")) + C(units, Treatment("1 unit"))
```

Is there any means where I can insert a beta coefficient for non-existent variables within the constructs of the StatsModels predict facility, preferably one from the prior year.  So, for example:

```
   Variable      Beta 2011  Beta 2012       Count 2012        Count 2013
   Loan Type A      -.05      -.08             2000              800
   Loan Type B      -.22      -.25             1000              1500  
   Loan Type C      -.38                                         500
```

If I did model2012.predict(data2013), an error would raise as there are observations and a regressor for Loan Type C in 2013 but none in 2012.  However, I would want to assume the 2011 beta coefficient for Loan Type C in the prediction of 2013 data using the 2012 parameters.

How can this be accomplished?  Any input would be greatly appreciated.